# Clean url without cleaning page variables

Tags: javascript, php

I have a site where I've tried to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
    var url = window.location.href;
        if ( url.split('?').length >= 2 ) {
            window.location = url.split("?")[0];
        }
    });           
</script>
```

To clean the url (website.com?id=12313). But on the website I also have a PHP script which reads this id. Is it even possible to use the above script and still make sure that the PHP Get variable reads it before the URL is cleaned.

Comment: Did you consider storing the variable in a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .htaccess may be one way to do it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [QSA,L] #rewrites all urls
```

Answer (score 1):

php will run long before that javascript does, therefore there is no risk in php not being able to read it. However, the moment you change the url with window.location, you're reloading the page and hitting php again, where it won't be able to find the id because you removed it.

The correct way to handle this is through server-side url rewriting. With apache, it's typically done through a `.htaccess`, and with IIS7, it's done with a `web.config`

Usually you don't want to remove the id completely, just make it cleaner.

`http://foo.com/12313`

if you remove the id completely, bookmarking won't work (and getting the id to and from php becomes very difficult)

An alternative would be to use the history api to change the url without causing a page refresh.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

```
// this is not supported in older browsers
history.pushState({}, "removed the id", "/");
```